# Check if an SDK is installed on Mobile (Vitamtio and .m3u8)

Tags: android, sdk, streaming, live

I'm Using Vitamio Lib to play (.m3u8) in my android application,,can i check if the user has the sdk on his mobile phone,,and if not give him the link to Download it?

Comment: The SDK as in Development Kit?, the user shouldn't even need the SDK, you need to include the library in your app so it gets packaged in the .apk file

Comment: I put it in the application ..but if it was not installed  ,the streaming won't work...

Comment: It Keep showing me this error if i did not install it..
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: io.vov.vitamio..
 at io.vov.vitamio.VitamioInstaller.checkVitamioInstallation(SourceFile:253)

Comment: The user needs to install the vitamio plugin (https://market.android.com/search?q=vitamio&c=apps), yo may need to remind the user to do so...

Comment: OK thank you...but can i check if the plug in is already installed ?

Comment: you can capture the exception thrown by the phone and show the user a text or something with the link to the downoad.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like bellow before starting your player

public boolean checkVitamioInstallation(final Context context) {

```
    try {
        VitamioInstaller.checkVitamioInstallation(context
                .getApplicationContext());

        return true;
    } catch (VitamioNotCompatibleException e) {
        TGLogger.e(this, "Not compatible", e);
        TGLogger.i(this, "Not compatible");
        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                        + VitamioInstaller.getCompatiblePackage());
                Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        marketUri);
                context.startActivity(marketIntent);

            }
        };
        Builder dialog = getDialog(context.getResources().getString(
                R.string.not_compatible_plugin), context.getResources()
                .getString(R.string.install_plugin_msg), context
                .getResources().getString(R.string.install_msg), context,
                listener);
        dialog.show();
    } catch (VitamioNotFoundException e) {
        TGLogger.e(this, "plugin not found", e);
        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                        + VitamioInstaller.getCompatiblePackage());
                Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        marketUri);
                context.startActivity(marketIntent);

            }
        };
        Builder dialog = getDialog(context.getResources().getString(
                R.string.plugin_not_found), context.getResources()
                .getString(R.string.fresh_plugin_install), context
                .getResources().getString(R.string.install_msg), context,
                listener);
        dialog.show();

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: bheema this is a good response. Where do you get vitamio library? I am looking for it but i can't find the jar files. can you give me url ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a current version of the Vitamio library in your app - when invoked the library will check itself whether Vitamio is installed and if not will prompt the user to download the relevant library APK from either the Android Marketplace or from the Vitamio website directly (if they don't have access to the Marketplace).